# How can i change the Camera component height in FirstPersonCharacter?

Tags: unity

The player looks very short. I changed his scale to 2,2,2 but the camera is in the middle it's like the player head is in the middle and not near the top.

In the screenshot in the Hierarchy i have a FPSController and the FirstPersonCharacter with the Camera is child of it. The FPSController scale set to 2,2,2 like the two soldiers. But you can see when i'm getting closer to the soldiers it looks like i'm looking at them from the ground.

I need to move the camera only up somehow.

[image: fpsc]

And this is the camera and the firstpersoncontroller before running the game:

[image: fpsc1]

Comment: Have you tried tweaking Character Controller's component Height property? I don't utilize standard assets, but I'm almost sure that modifying that re-adjusts the camera. The idea is to move that field and keep the scale as an unitary vector (all component at 1's) since having an object at scales different than '1' may result in ambiguous physics. Even playing with Character Controller's 'Center' field may modify the camera. If none of it works, simply move the camera upwards to the desired position.

Comment: I can see from the image you posted here that the fps camera is not at the top of the capsule collider. Try moving the camera as high as you need to see the soldiers correctly

Comment: Changing the FirstPersonCharacter Position Y value did the trick. Thank you.